# Android Wifi Signal Strength

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to get the list of available routers, their SSID's and signal strengths, by doing a wifi scan.
Can you please help me out with the code?

P.S.: I am new to android. A related Example will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Below code is used to get SSID, BSSID, IP Address & RSSI...

```
WifiManager wifi = = (WifiManager) uMobility.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);    

String ssid = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getSSID(); // for geting SSID
String bssid = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID(); // for geting BSSID
int ipAddress = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress(); // for geting IP Address
int rssi = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(); // for geting RSSI
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention the required permissions in the manifest. For the above code use ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission.
This is a good link to get a glimpse of the api http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html